# Unable to take differential backup using SQL Server VSS Writer

Tags: c++, sql-server, shadow-copy, volume-shadow-service

I have been trying to develop a tool to do backup/restore of MS SQL Server using SQL Server VSS Writer. I can not get the differntial backup working! I am just curious as to whether anyone ever made differential backup using VSS. Here is what I have been doing:

1. Create a full backup and store files and the Backup component document associated with it.
2. Update the tables in the database.
3. Create a new backup by setting '*SetBackupState*' as **VSS_BT_DIFFERENTIAL**
4. Now when adding the exisiting components to the Backup Component Document, I find the component's time stamp from the document in step 1, and then invoke it with '*SetPreviousBackupStamp*'
5. Now after the snapshot is taken, I go through each of the component and invoke '*GetPartialFileCount*' API. This always return the value 0. I am assuming if there is a change in an existing component, it should give a value greater than 0.

Am I missing something here? Do we need to start SQL Server VSS Writer using certain parameters or something? I tried different configurations including (Windows Server 2008/ SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 2):

I have been wanting to update this post for a while, but got tied up with all the bugs that I was finding in the program. Couple of folks from Microsoft helped me to nail down to the issue I had. I just want to thank Dileep and Ramesh (I am leaving out their last names for obvious reasons) for helping me get through this.

Here are my findings:

- SQL VSS Writer does support differential backup.
- When taking a differential backup, do not include "master" component as a component for backup.
- Always check for Writer status error after each phase using the following sequence of APIs: GatherWriterStatus(), GetWriterStatusCount(), GetWriterStatus()
- If the writer status points to an error, from there on things are unpredictable.
- The best place to start looking for finding the working is BETest source code available as part of VSS SDK.
- BETest allows backing up single database (Full/Differential) and restore (Full/Differential), so long as you get the /C option correctly. Components syntax is: "{Writer Id}":"Full Component Name"
  For example, for the database 'Person' on my machine my component info file contained:
  "{A65FAA63-5EA8-4EBC-9DBD-A0C4DB26912A}":"ABP-PC\SQLEXPRESS\Person";
- When doing a differential restore, the full restore needs to be done with "/AdditionalRestores" option.

Hope this helps. If somebody needs some help, update this post and I will get notified. I will help.

Comment: hi, i have problems with another writer and incremental backup, wrote all up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786843/possible-ways-to-do-incremental-backup-with-vss
can you help me in this? :)